# trying to change my leaving date UK

Tags: resignation, united-kingdom, notice-period

I am leaving my work for several reasons, including having to reduce my hours to care for my elderly parents, and also the stress I am under at work.

Due to my brother going into hospital, I want to be near home, as he currently is the carer.

I have found a part time job, which is near to home and I can dash home if the need arises, as I still have to pay some bills. The issue is that I only gave 6 weeks notice instead of the 3 months it says in a handbook I need to give, as this has all come along all of a sudden. My boss pointed this out when I gave him my letter and in the end just said, "I will sort things out".

Over three weeks have now gone, and up to now everyone I work with was under the impression that the date I gave would be the last date. But now my boss has come back and it going on about the 3 months notice again.He has kept asking me if I have changed my mind yet, and I am wondering if this is a way to try and make me stay by making things difficult, and he started saying he wasn't rushing into finding my replacement, even though we have interviewed several good candidates which could do my job.

I spoke to ACAS and they said that they felt that as it has been over 7 days, and my HR department had not rejected my resignation letter, or countered the date I put on it, it should stand, but I might have misunderstood what they meant.

Friends have told me to stick to my guns on this, and tell him I am leaving regardless, but I am still unsure, and I think sometimes I end up being pushed around by my boss on other occasions.

What should I do?

Comment: Is the leave notice in the handbook legally binding? If not, then leave according to the notice you gave. If the leave notice is legally binding then consult an attorney.

Answer (score 3):

Read your employment contract carefully. What exactly does it say about your notice period and specifically the consequences of leaving early ?

Then have a heart to heart with your boss. Let them know that you will be sticking to your plans: you appreciate his desire to keep you around but you have a family emergency you need to deal with and your last day of work will be XXX.

Keep repeating this to anyone who is asking consistently. Behave like everybody is on board with that (even if they don't).

Technically you may be "breach of contract" and the company could theoretically sue your or try to impose a financial penalty but that would be highly unlikely since a family emergency is an acceptable reason to not serve a full notice period.

Comment: Especially when the “compassion” shown gets known locally & company finds applicant numbers fall..

Answer (score 3):

If your contract says 3 months notice that means they *must* accept three months notice but are free to accept a shorter notice. it is common sense that an employee who doesn’t want to be there will be less productive or much less productive, so unless they really need you a company is not unlikely to agree.

ACAS may be right that the company has the right to refuse your notice, but that they actually have to tell you that it is refused or offer a different leaving date, otherwise the notice is accepted.

Other than that, you can let your manager know that you *have* to leave after six weeks to look after your parents and that you will dash home if needed. The worst thing that can happen is getting fired, and you said you have a new job.